# Service unavailable the service is temporarily unavailable error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, apache, lamp

I am using lamp. What i did is i have a php page with a send message to all button in ajax.  When i click that button it calls the function in  backend and send message to 10 users and then shows me result on sending every 10 users.  It works some time and it doesnt work many times.

Error i saw on console on chrome : "500 internal server error"
and when i clicked on that link and clicked on that link it showed me : "Service unavailable.  The service is temporarily unavailable.  Please try again later".

I thought it might be timeout issue i also used "set_time_limit(0)".  But still it failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
   Aby

Comment: A 500 error is not a timeout issue. It says "500 internal server error" meaning that there's an error either in your configuration or your code. You'll have to check the error logs to find out.

Comment: hi there i dont see any errors in error_log

Comment: This is an old article, but shows good debugging tips for PHP http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/

Comment: thanks speeves.  It works fine on my test machine but i dont know some how its not working fine on production.

Comment: I have also added a try and catch to that loop though it didnt catch the error there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an 500 error.  Please try checking your error logs.